# Trouble computing covariance and variance

Tags: r, covariance, variance

I want to compute the covariance and the variance of two times series but for some reason, I always get a "NA" answer. My data seems to be fine, they are real numbers without special features. The code looks like this:

```
> a = cov(dtarussell, dtasp)
> b = var(dtarussell)
> a
>[1] NA
> b
>[1] NA
```

The vectors I use are excess returns of `russell 2000` and `s&p 500`and they don't have any "NA" value.

Comment: please provide some data for `dtarussell` and `dtasp`

Comment: Sure ! It looks like this :

for (i in m) 
{dtarussell = excess_russel[i:i+30]
dtasp = excess_rsp[i:i+30]
regression_rolling = lm(dtarussell~dtasp)
coe = coefficients(regression_rolling)
alfa_rolling_month[i] = coe[1]}

and excess_russel first values are:

[1] -0.01315129 -0.02057723 -0.02154304
 [4] -0.01911930 -0.01928968 -0.01516093
 [7] -0.01827083 -0.01965425 -0.01806476
[10] -0.01663093

excess_rsp first values are:

[1] -0.01786350 -0.02404809 -0.02326127
 [4] -0.02210031 -0.01808796 -0.01137800
 [7] -0.02457202 -0.03104334 -0.01981456
[10] -0.01237236